# laravel map user table to existing table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i want to implement an api with laravel for an existing app. Here we have already a user tabel with other name und fieldnames.
I tried to map the fieldnames in the User Model with the following snippet:

```
...
use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

public $timestamps = false;
protected $table = 'benutzer';

protected $maps =[
    "id" => "id",
    "name" => "app_user_id",
    "email" => "email",               
    "password" => "kennwort",
    "email_verified_at" => "agb_zentrale_akzeptiert_datum"
];...
```

unfortunately when I send a post request to register a user I get a sql error back, while in my benutzer table the name is stored in the field app_user_id

so what do i miss or do i wrong here

Georg

Comment: We need to see your error before we can help you with said error.

Answer (score 0):

The `protected $maps = []` is not an official Laravel feature.

I assume you have forgotten to install the following package https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence given the `$maps =[` seems to be copy-pasted from their documentation with the same no spacing between `=[`

A thorough installation guide can be found at the package documentation here: https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence/wiki/Installation